# filter nest array of object using java script

Tags: javascript

This the data i need this value only **email": "gm@gmail.com"**

```
{
  "params": {
    "user": {
      "address1": "790 7th Ave",
      "address2": "hhhdkhdskhsdkh",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "name": "gm4",
      "phone": "",
      "state": "TN",
      "zipcode": "600008"
    },
    "query": {
      "FILTERS": [
        [
          {
            "EQ": {
              "email": "gm@gmail.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "PAGENUM": 1,
      "PAGESIZE": 100,
      "SELECTCOLUMNS": [],
      "SORT": []
    },
    "trigger": "User::UserUpdated"
  },
  "context": {}
}
```

actually, I tried const out = req.params.query.FILTERS[0].EQ.email
but i field unable to get expect result plz help.

Comment: your `FILTERS` are array of arrays... so probably try `req.params.query.FILTERS[0][0].EQ.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a nested array.

```
req.params.query.FILTERS[0][0].EQ.email
```